# If statement not working when using Jquery .focus()

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

In an MVC application I want to set the focus on a textbox only if a model property is set to true. Here is the Jquery code I'm using:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            var isPostBack = $("#IsPostBack").val();
            if (isPostBack) {
                $('#MyElement').focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>`

`IsPostBack` is a hidden field containing a boolean value. For some reason this simply always sets the focus on `MyElement`. As if `IsPostBack` were always true. However, strangely it seems to work properly when I debug in Firebug. What is going on here?

Comment: what is the value of `isPostBack`? is it empty string or `false`

Comment: the value of IsPostBack is always either true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your value might be string **"false"**, and `"false" != false`,  so try changing your `isPostBack` to,

```
var isPostBack = ($("#IsPostBack").val() == "true") ? true : false;
```

**Updated::** you could convert your value to lowercase and compare, as:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var isPostBackStr = $.trim( $("#IsPostBack").val() ); 
    isPostBackStr = isPostBackStr.toLowerCase();
    var isPostBack = ( isPostBackStr == "true") ? true : false;
    if (isPostBack) { 
        $('#MyElement').focus(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: I think "true" needs to be capitalized.

Comment: @navig8tr it depends on whether your value is TRUE or true

Comment: in the controller it was set to true, but for some reason in the dom it was set to True.

Comment: in that case you can change to :: ($("#IsPostBack").val() == "True")

Comment: Yup, that's what I used

Comment: @navig8tr see my addition, you could lowercase your value and then compare it against true

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `isPostBack` has a string value `'false'` which is always truthy

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var isPostBack = $("#IsPostBack").val();
        if (isPostBack == 'true') {
            $('#MyElement').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @navig8tr yes... that depends on the actual value of the input